# Rails & Amazon RDS: "production database is not configured"

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm brand new to all things AWS, and trying to boot up my Rails app on Beanstalk. I'm following the [recent tutorial](http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx2AK2MFX0QHRIO/Deploying-Ruby-Applications-to-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk-with-Git), but I'm stuck getting my app connected to RDS. The passenger screen comes up with an error:

```
production database is not configured (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

My `database.yml` looks like:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

I do have an RDS instance configured and running. I also ssh'ed into the EC2 instance, and verified that I can successfully connect to the RDS via RDS_USERNAME, RDS_HOSTNAME, etc.

Thinking that perhaps I needed to manually create my database in MySQL I used the MySQL client to do that, but I still get the same error.

So again on the EC2 instance I checked out my project manually and ran `bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace` to get a more complete picture of where it's failing:

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
rake aborted!
production database is not configured
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:39:in `resolve_string_connection'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:129:in `establish_connection'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:721:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:227:in `call'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:227:in `block in execute'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:222:in `each'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:222:in `execute'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:185:in `each'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:185:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in `invoke'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:141:in `invoke_task'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `each'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `block in top_level'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `top_level'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:71:in `block in run'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:158:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:68:in `run'
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/bin/rake:37:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was user error: copy/paste from the linked article resulted in "spaces" that were apparently some unicode cruft rather than ASCII 32.

Lesson learned: use `od -c your_file.yml` to diagnose potential funny chars.